# is there a graphical interpretation for the integral of a single parameter vector-valued function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, graphing-functions, intuition

On single variable calculus integrals have a nice graphical interpretation as the area under the curve of a function $f(x)=y$ who's graph is built with 2 axis where the $x$ axis is the domain and the $y$ axis is the image of the function.

I would like to know if, Given some single parameter vector valued function, for example $f(t)=<x(t),y(t),z(t)>$, is there any **graphical** interpretation (or intuition) for $\int f(t)\,dt$?

Note: My question is limited to functions with domains in $\mathbb{R}^1$ but NOT limited to functions with images in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: You should know that what you've written down is not what you've encountered. $\int f(t)\,dt$ (you left out the $dt$) is the integral of a vector function, so it just integrates each component individually. But that is *not* what usual line (path) integrals are at all.

Comment: Thanks for the intent on foresight, I dont think I have encountered line integrals yet.  When I wrote $\int f(t)\,dt$ I did mean the integral of a vector function of a single parameter, which is indeed as far as i know just the integral of each component individually. I just added the $\,dt$, sorry im not used to write it down when I only have a single variable.

Comment: Yeah, then that's all you can say. If you talk about the line integral $\int_C f\,ds$ of a function over a curve $C$, integrating with respect to arclength, then you can generalize the interpretation you have in mind. Make a fence with height $f(x)$ over the point $x$ of the curve $C$ (going into one more dimension with the fence). The integral then gives you the area of that fence (if you unroll it into a plane, for example).

Comment: Interestng. Im just getting bits and pices of what you say . My calculus course kind of goes from derivatives and integrals of functions $f:\mathbb{R}^1 \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (and it does not talk about line integrals, it does talk about getting arclength using integrals tho),then it just seems to go to derivatives and integrals on functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^1$ (partial derivatives and the like). I will look line integrals up to see what's the deal with that.

Comment: It may or may not be of interest or helpful, but you might want to check out my YouTube videos. There's perhaps more applications — and definitely more rigor and proofs — than in many multivariable courses; but it's all integrated with the linear algebra needed to make sense of the concepts carefully.

Comment: This playlist? I see line integrals are introduced very late, I'm about 30% in my course so that may have something to do with it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hX0QePiWlw&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd

Answer (score 1):

You can think of $\textbf{a}(t) = (a_{1}(t),a_{2}(t),a_{3}(t))$ as the acceleration of a moving particle within $\textbf{R}^{3}$. Consequently, its integral between the instants $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ gives the difference between its inicial and final velocities, respectively.

Similarly, you can think of $\textbf{v}(t) = (v_{1}(t),v_{2}(t),v_{3}(t))$ as the velocity of a moving particle within $\textbf{R}^{3}$. Consequently, its integral between the instants $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ gives the difference between its inicial and final position, respectively.

Another interesting example comes from physics as well. Let us consider the resultant force acting upon a particle is expressible as a function $\textbf{F}:\textbf{R}^{3}\rightarrow\textbf{R}^{3}$, where $\textbf{s}:\textbf{R}\rightarrow\textbf{R}^{3}$ is the function which expresses its position over time. Then the work corresponding to the time interval $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
W = \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\langle\textbf{F}(\textbf{s}(t)),\textbf{s}'(t)\rangle\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im familiar with this, but it's not a relationship that has a geometric meaning in the graphs (at least I understand it as the relationship between the integral and the antiderivative).

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan I don't have an answer for you, but I can say that graphical interpretation is not necessarily the best thing to look for. The reason is because as soon the input and output spaces dimensions add up to more than $3$, a graph is not the natural setting for objects such as functions. Functions and their graphs are distinct objects and it is helpful to begin to think of them as such when progressing to more math.

Comment: Thanks. With time I have come to realize that the more angles, perspectives and intuitions I can merge into a single math concept the better I understand it and I can use it with more flexibility to solve problems.That's why I asked the question. Maybe the answer at the end is that the graphical interpretation has no relevance at all, and that's usefull to know in itself.